# How to console each value of number array with setInterval of the value as seconds Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

let listofRandom = [ ]

console each value I push into that array, with certain time intervals

For example:  let listofRandom = [5, 1, 7 ]

Here 1st value is 5 which means it has to console the "5" for every 5 seconds and the next value is 1 has to console the "1" for every 1 second and then console "7" for every 7 seconds.

```
let listofRandom = [];
let generatedValues = '';

const addValue = () => {
let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
listofRandom.push(value);
console.log(listofRandom)
};

  listofRandom.map((num) => {
return setInterval(function () {
  generatedValue = generatedValue + num.toString(); 
  console.log(generatedValue); 
}, num * 1000);
});
return(
<button onclick="addValue()">Add Value To Array </button>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState([1, 5, 7]);

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        let counter = count;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (counter >= values.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                console.log(values[counter]);
                setCount((count) => count + 1);
                counter++;
            }
        }, values[counter] * 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let listofRandom = [5, 1, 7];
listofRandom.map((num) => {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(num);
  }, num * 1000)});
```